# r: barplot - legends issue

Tags: r, bar-chart, legend-properties

[image: Product Sales per month**strong text**]

How can I get rid of the boxes in legends and get colored lines instead? Also, how do I place them at a corner?
This is the command I am using:

```
barplot(as.matrix(month_wise_data), main="Product sold per month",
    xlab="Products", col=brewer.pal(nrow(month_wise_data), "Paired"),legend = as.character(month_wise_data[,"MONTH"]), beside=TRUE,
    args.legend=list(x=100,y=10,bty = "n",pt.lwd=0.1, ncol = 3, cex=0.5,pch=1))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add a separate `legend` call like so:

```
barplot(VADeaths,beside =TRUE,col=1:5,ylim=c(0,100))
legend("topleft",legend=rownames(VADeaths),col=1:5,lty=1)
```

[image]